# Deserialize certain JSON properties into subclass

Tags: c#, json, serialization

```
public class ApiResponse<T> : IApiResponse<T>
{
    public long QuotaRemaining { get; set; }
    public long QuotaMax { get; set; }
    public int Backoff { get; set; }
    public bool HasMore { get; set; }
    public long Total { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    //public long ErrorId { get; set; }
    //public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    //public string ErrorName { get; set; }
    public IList<T> Items { get; set; }

    public ApiError Error { get; set; }
}

public class ApiError
{   
    [JsonProperty("error_id")]
    public long ErrorId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("error_message")]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("error_name")]
    public string ErrorName { get; set; }
}
```

Thing is the `Error` properties are actually at the same level as `ApiResponse<T>`, but I'd like to wrap them into an `ApiError` class, how could I accomplish this?

I'm currently deserializing like this:

```
    public static T DeserializeJson<T>(this string json)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    }
```

I guess there's some set of attributes that allows me to accomplish this pretty easily, but I can't figure out what that configuration should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pick and choose which properties are serialized by decorating them.

Adding [ScriptIgnore] will cause the property to not be serialized.  This doesn't really create a subclass, but does provide a way to only serialize selected properties.

Disclaimer: I have only ever done this using the `JavaScriptSerializer` class to create the JSON.

**Example:**

```
public class ApiResponse<T> : IApiResponse<T>
{
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public long QuotaRemaining { get; set; }
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public long QuotaMax { get; set; }
    public int Backoff { get; set; }
    public bool HasMore { get; set; }
}
```

In the above class, only the `Backoff` and `HasMore` properties will be serialized.

Comment: I know that, I can do that with `[JsonIgnore]`, but I would like to serialize those three into the subclass.